# Trouble with applying Styles in - OpenPyXL

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to style specific rows and columns.

```
worksheet.cell(row=file_row_number, column=1).value = "Hotel ID"
_cell = worksheet.cell("C1")
_cell.style.font.bold = True
```

It shows me error

```
TypeError: cannot set bold attribute
```

Previously I was using `XLWT` and it had very easy method of applying styles like you define `style` variable once and then for ever `write()` yo can just pass the `style` variable to apply style on that row/column

Is there any way in `OpenPyXL` to apply style easily as I mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/styles.html), you should first create a `Style` object:

```
from openpyxl.styles import Style, Font

s = Style(font=Font(bold=True))
```

Then you can apply it to your cell like this:

```
_cell.style = s
```

Comment: Got it ... .... I have one more confusion ... can I write a value and apply a style in one line??? like my below comment ... I am writing value and applying style in 2 lines ... can it be done in 1 ine?

Comment: `worksheet.cell(row=file_row_number, column=1).value = "Hotel ID"`
# applyig style
`worksheet.cell(row=file_row_number, column=1).style = Style(font=Font(bold=True))`

Comment: To the best of my knowledge you need two instructions to change value and applying a style. You cannot do both in 1 line.

Comment: how can i set width of column?

Answer (score 8):

This has changed since the accepted answer was given.

If you do what the accepted answer suggests, you will receive this warning:
UserWarning: Use formatting objects such as font directly
  warn("Use formatting objects such as font directly")

The answer still works but the new solution would be to apply it to the cell directly, for example:
`worksheet.cell("C1").font = Font(bold=True)`

Comment: If you want to iterate through a range of cells, here is an example:
`for row in worksheet.iter_rows('A1:L1'):
    for cell in row:
        cell.number_format = '0'
        cell.font = Font(bold=True)`