# Applying colors to cell in openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to apply background colors in cell based on the value of the cell in openpyxl but getting errors, can someone have some working examples?
I tried applying styles as well

```
 from openpyxl.styles import colors,Style
 mystyle=Style()
 mystyle.fill.bgColor = colors.DARKBLUE
 cell.style=mystyle
```

> Warning (from warnings module):
>     File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\styleable.py", line 189
>       warn("Use formatting objects such as font directly")
>   UserWarning: Use formatting objects such as font directly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble with applying Styles in - OpenPyXL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954788/trouble-with-applying-styles-in-openpyxl)

Comment: This is more than adequately covered in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would solve it:

```
def colors():
    colors.gray = PatternFill(start_color='aabbcc',
               end_color='aabbcc',
               fill_type='solid')

if cell(row=x, column=y).value == 'your value':
    cell(row=i, column=14).fill = colors.gray
```